# Netbeans and Maven Project: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm getting this exception without even coding, it appears just as soon as I want to create a new Maven Project in netbeans. Why is this error coming up if I didn't even write any code. I'm using netbeans 8 and bundled maven. Proxu has been configured and when testing the connection it says Ok. Please help!

EDIT: I'm adding the stacktrace that is displayed in netbeans

```
constituent[0]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/aether-api-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[1]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/aether-api-1.13.1.jar
constituent[2]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/aether-connector-basic-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[3]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/aether-connector-wagon-1.13.1.jar
constituent[4]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[5]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/aether-impl-1.13.1.jar
constituent[6]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/aether-spi-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[7]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/aether-spi-1.13.1.jar
constituent[8]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/aether-transport-wagon-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[9]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[10]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/aether-util-1.13.1.jar
constituent[11]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
constituent[12]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar
constituent[13]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
constituent[14]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar
constituent[15]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar
constituent[16]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/guava-18.0.jar
constituent[17]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[18]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/jsoup-1.7.2.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
constituent[20]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.0.5.jar
constituent[21]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.3.jar
constituent[22]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-artifact-3.0.5.jar
constituent[23]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.3.jar
constituent[24]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-builder-support-3.3.3.jar
constituent[25]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-compat-3.0.5.jar
constituent[26]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-compat-3.3.3.jar
constituent[27]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-core-3.0.5.jar
constituent[28]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-core-3.3.3.jar
constituent[29]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-embedder-3.0.5.jar
constituent[30]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-embedder-3.3.3.jar
constituent[31]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-model-3.0.5.jar
constituent[32]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-model-3.3.3.jar
constituent[33]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-model-builder-3.0.5.jar
constituent[34]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-model-builder-3.3.3.jar
constituent[35]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.0.5.jar
constituent[36]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.3.3.jar
constituent[37]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.0.5.jar
constituent[38]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.3.3.jar
constituent[39]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-settings-3.0.5.jar
constituent[40]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-settings-3.3.3.jar
constituent[41]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.0.5.jar
constituent[42]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.3.3.jar
constituent[43]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.0.jar
constituent[44]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.0.jar
constituent[45]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[46]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
constituent[47]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
constituent[48]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar
constituent[49]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
constituent[50]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar
constituent[51]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
constituent[52]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar
constituent[53]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
constituent[54]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/sisu-guice-3.2.5-no_aop.jar
constituent[55]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar
constituent[56]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/sisu-inject-plexus-2.3.0.jar
constituent[57]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
constituent[58]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
constituent[59]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/wagon-file-2.4.jar
constituent[60]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/wagon-file-2.9.jar
constituent[61]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/wagon-http-2.4-shaded.jar
constituent[62]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/wagon-http-2.9-shaded.jar
constituent[63]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/wagon-http-shared-2.9.jar
constituent[64]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/wagon-provider-api-2.4.jar
constituent[65]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%208.0/java/maven/lib/wagon-provider-api-2.9.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; from class com.google.inject.internal.Annotations$AnnotationChecker
    at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations$AnnotationChecker.<init>(Annotations.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations.<clinit>(Annotations.java:122)
    at com.google.inject.Key.ensureRetainedAtRuntime(Key.java:362)
    at com.google.inject.Key.strategyFor(Key.java:354)
    at com.google.inject.Key.get(Key.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ParameterKeys.<clinit>(ParameterKeys.java:28)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$ContainerModule.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:832)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:229)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.MergedModule.configure(MergedModule.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:229)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:136)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: exception without stacktrace is useless, you would be better off filing an issue with netbeans.org with attached log file. - http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile

Comment: I'll add the stack trace.

Comment: Please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have both maven 3.0.5 and 3.3.3 binaries on the same classpath. Netbeans 8.0 AFAIK ships with 3.0.5 only. It could a messed up installation:
1. try deleting the current installation, redownload and reinstall. 
2. if that doesn't help, could be related to some custom plugin you have installed. I'm not aware of any such plugin but it's something to double check, if found, uninstall + restart IDE.
3. if these don't help, file an issue at netbeans.org

Comment: I'll try to reinstall then and accept this as the correct answer if it starts working. Thanks for your reply!